# Recurrence relation for a sequence

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Find a recurrence for the number of words of length n in the alphabet {1,2,...,k} with no 11. $n\in \mathbb{P}$ with $k \geq2$.

Please help me.....

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE! Please note that $\LaTeX$ is the preferred format for writing Mathematics here. Also, please try and have a descriptive title, and then a self-contained question. Finally, please show us what your thoughts on the problem are, and where are you stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this question has been answered a thousand times before but for a given sequence, consider the case the sequence ends in $1$ or it doesn't:

If it ends in $1$, then the number of possible sequences we can make are $(r-1) W_r(n-2)$.  If it doesn't end in $1$, the number of possible sequences we can have are $(r-1)W_r(n-1)$.

This gives us the recurrence relationship:

$$ W_r(n) = (r-1) (W_r(n-1) + W_r(n-2))$$

**Solving for $W_r(n)$:**

Let $f_r(n)$ be the number of such sequences ending in $1$ and $g_r(n)$ be the number of such sequences not ending in $1$.

Then we have the two relations: $$f_r(n+1) =  g_r(n)$$
$$ g_r(n+1) = (r - 1) (f_r(n-1) + g_r(n-1)) $$

If we then

Writing this as a matrix equation:

$$ \left( \begin{array}{c} f_r(n+1) \\ g_r(n+1) \end{array}\right) =  \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ r-1 & r-1 \end{array}\right) \left( \begin{array}{c} f_r(n) \\ g_r(n) \end{array}\right)$$

We are interested in calculating $$ W_r(n) = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1\end{array}\right) A^{n-1} \left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ r-1 \end{array}\right) $$

where $A$ is the matrix in the matrix equation.  We can then diagonalise $A$ and come up with an exact solution.

Comment: Using the recurrence relation $W_{r}(n)=(r-1)(W_{r}(n-1)+W_{r}(n-2))$, $W_{4}(4)=165$ but it should be $W_{4}(4)=216$.

Comment: $W_4(1) = r = 4, W_4(2) = r^2 - 1 = 15.$  This means $W_4(3) = 57$ and then $W_4(4) = 72 \cdot 3 = 216$.  ie) Your calculation for $W_4(3)$ is wrong.

Comment: REALLY APPRECIATE YOUR HELP!!!!